# HTTP Post request json data changes

Tags: javascript, node.js

For some weird reason, when I have my client send an HTTP Post request to my server, the data changes. Everytime I console.log the data in server, my data no longer has commas. Instead, it replaces every single comma with &. Why are all my commas changing to the `&` symbols and how do I fix this?

Client:

```
var request = require('request');
request.post('http://11.11.11.111:9000/server.js', {form:{ "id" : "42", "helpme" : "no"}})
```

Server:

```
req.on('data', function(chunk) {
     //file1=chunk;
     file1=JSON.parse(chunk);
     console.log(file1);
}
```

Comment: The event handler takes a `chunk` argument but you're parsing `data`?

Comment: Sorry, I miswrote it. It is parsing the chunk. Also, there marks no difference between `=chunk` and `JSON.parse(chunk)`. Both print out the same string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the `form` option for `request`, use the `json` option:

```
request.post('http://11.11.11.111:9000/server.js', {
  json : { "id" : "42", "helpme" : "no"}
})
```

Also, be aware that multiple `data` events can be generated, each containing incomplete data. You need to store the incoming data and parse it at the end:

```
var chunks = [];
req.on('data', function(chunk) {
  chunks.push(chunk);
});
req.on('end', function() {
  var data = JSON.parse( Buffer.concat(chunks) );
  ...
});
```